# Screen repaint problem with emacs and terminals

Tags: 11.10, gnome, screen, emacs

When I'm using emacs in ubuntu 11.10, I have the following problem: I navigate with C-N and C-P, sometimes screen is not correctly updated and I see the text garbled. Sometimes I have a similar problem with the terminal as well. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: this is a bug in nvidia, you might find a solution here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-180/+bug/303224